# How to install apt in Docker machine?

Tags: docker, apt

I'm SSH'd into a Docker VM (the default machine) and did a `apt-get update` and this is what I got:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not a huge Linux user; how do I install `apt` in a Docker machine? I'm ultimately wanting to install `vim` and/or `nano` via `apt-install` on the machine.

Comment: What OS is this using? Try just `apt` instead of `apt-get`.

Comment: @MattB I'm guessing Tinycorelinux based on the screenshot? :P I just tried `apt` by itself but same result: `-bash: apt: command not found`

Comment: Ha of course..! Worth a shot. Not 100% sure which package manager tinycore has, if any?

Comment: Try `tce-load` instead. `tce-load -wi vim.tcz` and `tce-load -wi nano.tcz`
Do run the docker image with `--privileged` mode.

Comment: The `nano` is more recommended. Vim needs more dependencies.

Comment: @CharlesXu you're right, I just looked it up and vim is like 1.4mb while nano is 104kb. YUGE difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with TinyCore distribution and installing apt is not a good selection. instead you could use [lubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/r/teresaejunior/lubuntu/)

TinyCore Dist comes with `tce-load` package. Which you can use to download the packages. example:
`tce-load -wi vim.tcz` or `tce-load -wi nano.tcz`

Answer (score 1):

ASR has the correct answer. I just wanted to include some things in case others read this post.

A list of available packages for Tiny Core Linux (TCL) is here (note, I have TCL `version` 8.2.1 installed and this list of showing for TCL version 10.x, but I think the package names stay the same for the most part):

http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/10.x/x86/tcz/

And a TCL cheat sheet for installing packages is here:

http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:package_management_cheat_sheet

End result: =)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

As there are no package managers apt, yum, apk inside docker machine, my case docker toolbox on Windows, and windows does not dispone with Linux package managers unless using cygwin or other workaround, I used Windows 10 Pro Ubuntu subsystem, where it is possible to use apt.